# OpenCVSharp UMat directly to the WritableBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

I use OpenCvSharp4.Windows (4.7.0.20230115) with OpenCvSharp4.Extensions (4.7.0.20230115) with a net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0 targetFramework.

I have an initialized WriteableBitmap and got frames from RTSP and doing some modification with OpenCVSharp in GPU. This code is after the modifications:

```
Mat resizedImage= ((UMat)image).GetMat(AccessFlag.READ); //Memory copy

wb.WritePixels(dirtyRect, resizedImage.Data, resizedImage.Rows * resizedImage.Cols * 4, wb.BackBufferStride); //Memory copy
```

My problem is that these two lines are two copy of the image. For example if I use GPU without dedicated RAM these are two normal memory copies.

Is it possible that copy UMat data to the WriteableBitmap data for better performance?

Thanks!

Comment: WritePixels does not create an extra "memory copy" of the pixel data. It directly copies the bytes from the input buffer to its BackBuffer.

Comment: `wb.BackBufferStride` is also only by accident a correct value here. It should instead be the stride of the buffer in `resizedImage.Data`, which should be `resizedImage.Cols * 4`.

Comment: 1. But the WritePixels do a memory copy.  And the GetMat also doing a memory copy. So it is two copy, and I want to reduce it to one. Directly from UMat to the WB.

2. Ok, i see, thanks the correction! :)